# Can't find out where passing variable to Jade title in Sails project

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, sails.js

I initial a new `Sails` project and set `Jade` as template engine. At this time I don't have any controller and model.

Below is the code in `layout.jade`.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title

    // Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support
    meta(name="viewport",content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1")

    block styles

  body
    block body

    // A few key dependencies, linked in order

    // Bring in the socket.io client
    script(type="text/javascript", src="/scripts/js/socket.io.js")

    // then beef it up with some convenience logic for talking to Sails.js'
    script(type="text/javascript", src="/scripts/js/sails.io.js")

    // listen on socket.io for incoming messages
    script(type="text/javascript", src="/scripts/js/app.js")
```

In title tag:

```
title= title
```

I couldn't find out the title variable assign expression in home/index page & layout, and route is simple:

```
'/': {
  view: 'home/index'
}
```

Didn't through any controller.But title compile to

```
<title>Sails</title>
```

Where is the title variable's value come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it defaults to the application's name so that you never have a blank title.

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/request/locals.js#L46

Comment: Wow, I never thought of anything inner modules. Your answer is helpful! thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I'm setting my page title through the /config/routes.js like this.

```
'get /': {
  view: 'homepage',
  locals: {
    page: {
      title: 'Home'
    }
  }
}
```